# Content wont go after a <%yield%> in my application.html.erb file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with the content of my application page in rails,I basically cannot put any content after the <% yield %> tag.

My problem is that when I put a footer underneath the <% yield %> it shows up over the yield content, not bellow.  I am sure there is a simple solution for this but I just cannot get it to work as I would like to.

I anyone have an idea of were the problem could be would be really helpful.

```html
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <%= link_to (image_tag("logo.png", class:"food-image")), root_path%>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="sections"><%= link_to 'Dishes', posts_path %></li>
          <li class="sections"><%= link_to 'Events', posts_path %></li>
          <li class="sections"><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
            <ul class="social-icons">
              <li class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></li>
              <li class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></li>
              <li class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></li>
              <li class="fa fa-pinterest fa-2x"></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>

      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav> 

  <% if current_page?(root_path) %>
    <div class="image-header">
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="anchor">
  </div>

  <%= yield %>

  <footer>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="logs">
      <div class="login-buttons">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <button><%= link_to "New Post", new_post_path , class:"sing_in"%></button>
          <button><%= link_to("Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, class:"sing_in") %></button>
        <% else %>
          <button><%= link_to("Login", new_user_session_path, class:"sing_in") %></button>
      <% end %>
      </div>
      <p>lnjkbhjghfxgdzfxgchvjbknl</p>
      <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
      <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
    </div><!-- container-fluid-->
  </footer>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a CSS problem. If there's a float in the yield somewhere, you could need to clear it. Immediately after the yield and before footer, insert a spacer ...

```
<div style="clear:both"> </div>
```

Hopefully that puts you on the right track.